# I wish to find how the package was installed

Tags: 12.04, server, apt

I was going to upgrade a package in ubuntu and had a doubt how was it installed in server. How can I check if it was installed from source i.e. using make command or via apt-get/yum?

I have searched lot of forums but was confused. Can I check it via rpm qa command as in centos?

Sorry if the question is too simple but I was not getting the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the package is installed by compiling manually then `apt-get`/`dpkg` would not have any track of the package, and hence it's contents.

You can check if `dpkg` has any track of the installed package:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep 'package_name_or_pattern'
```

or

```
dpkg -l 'package_name_or_pattern'
```